# Value is the variable name instead of the contents of the variable

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to initialise some data values dynamically inside a javascript object, but when I create a concatenated string to pass along, the actual key stored is the variable name, instead of the value inside it.

Example:

```
projects.init = function(){
    for (var i = this.numBoxes - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        var toInject = "item"+i;
        this.datas[i] = {toInject:"testdata"};
    };
}
```

Then after calling init, the values inside projects.datas look like.. toInject "testdata", instead of being "item1"..."item2".... what am I doing wrong..?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should build your object in two steps, and use the bracket notation [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Member_Operators):

```
projects.init = function(){
        for (var i = this.numBoxes - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                var toInject = "item"+i,
                    obj = {};

                obj[toInject] = "testdata";
                this.datas[i] = obj;
        };
}
```

The labels on object literals cannot be expressions.

As you can see, first you declare an empty [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Literals):

```
var obj = {};
```

And then you set the property:

```
obj[toInject] = "testdata";
```

Comment: Is there a reference explaining this in more detail? I'm sure this works, but would be nice to know why ;)

Comment: obj[toInject] is like saying eval( "obj." + toInject); it sets the property with the name in the variable toInject. :D

Comment: It's fairly simple.  Property ID's in JSON are not allowed to be variables.  If you want to use a variable to reference or create a property, you have to use array notation as CMS has shown.

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer: There are some property names that cannot be accessed by the dot notation, for example a property name that contains a (`-`) dash, evaling that will just make a syntax error, because the compiler will find the dash and it will interpret it as the arithmetic substraction operator, in an invalid operation.

Comment: Unquoted words in object literal keys being taken as strings: another of JavaScript's bizarre mistakes.